# How to attach multiple azure scale set as a target type in azure application gateway backend pool using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-application-gateway

How can I attach different Azure scale sets as a target type under different azure application gateway backend pool using terraform?

My requirements:

1. One application gateway
2. Multiple backend pools.
3. Each backend pool has its own azure scaleset as the target type